# Make a POST request with HttpClient in UWP(W10)

Tags: c#, post, uwp, httpclient

I'm using the Universal Windows Plataform for making a App and I want to ask how to post data like (id=1) to the server with httpclient.
I know that there is some tutorials on internet, but many of them are for Windows 8.1 and don't work in 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to handle HTTP request in UWP, you need a webservice to support it. If you make a web API project in your solution, then you can use the actions inside controllers to handle the POST request.

More reading about web API: [click here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

First you need to install the web API .net Client from NuGet to handle HTTP request from web API.

in your UWP project, you can then make a Data transfer class with the following method:

```
const string ServerUrl = ""; //specify your server url

 public void ClientHeaderInfo(HttpClient client)
 {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ServerUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
 }

public virtual async Task Post(int id,string url)
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            ClientHeaderInfo(client);
            try
            {
                await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, id);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await new MessageDialog(ex.Message).ShowAsync();
            }
        }

    }
```

Now you can call the Post method where ever you need it, with the url routing to the desired controller in the web API, and the id you need to POST.

Comment: well... i'm currently using UWP, Windows 10 and handling POST request with this. So if you are using the last updated version then yours will work to.

Comment: you need to add a web api .net client from NuGet to support the following

Comment: Ok thnks, I'll try it!

Comment: Install-Package : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'SDFA'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Any idea about a possible fix?

Comment: try to to install using the Package Manager Console with this: Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client

Comment: Yes, this is a log from the console

Comment: try to delete all the folders inside of the packages folder and then update all packages in Nuget Package Manager.

Comment: I found a method with the Dictionary, Thnks for the help