# Trying out a tutorial for getting JSON data from a web API and I stumbled on this error while the video did not encounter this error

Tags: c#, json, api

All it tells me to do is change GetResponse to either:  EndGetResponse(), BeginGetResponse() or GetResponseAsync()﻿

The error message reads: 'HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponse' and no extension method 'GetResponse' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing an assembly reference?)

and I'm getting an error on this specific section:

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            if(response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                throw new Exception("error code:" + response.StatusCode.ToString());
```

This was the code in said video:

```
public enum httpVerb
{
    GET,
    POST,
    PUT,
    DELETE
}

class RestClient
{
    public string endPoint { get; set; }
    public httpVerb httpMethod { get; set; }

    public RestClient()
    {
        endPoint = string.Empty;
        httpMethod = httpVerb.GET;
    }

    public string makeRequest()
    {
        string strResponseValue = string.Empty;

        HttpWebRequest request =      (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);

        request.Method = httpMethod.ToString();

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            if(response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                throw new Exception("error code:" + response.StatusCode.ToString());
            }

            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if(responseStream != null)
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        strResponseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return strResponseValue;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Mind showing us the video?

Comment: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11f5KzVNQ90) thats the one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the specifics of the video or what the rest of your code/project look like I can only go by the error:

`HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponse' and no extension method 'GetResponse' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Have you checked your assembly references to see if you have a reference to System.Net?

**EDIT**

It seems like you might be confusing using statements with assembly references.  Although your class file contains using statements to System.Net, your project itself might not have a reference to the System.Net dll.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) is a quick guide on how to manage those references in Visual Studio.

As a quick check:

1. Find the `References` section in your Visual Studio project.
2. Right Click `References'
3. Click `Add Reference`
4. In the `Assemblies` > `Framework` section verify that `System.Net` is checked

**EDIT #2**

It looks like you created a UWP project instead of the video's perscribed Windows Form project type.  The reason you are getting errors in your code is because the GetResponse() method of HttpWebRequest cannot be used in UWP projects.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38871200/2457029) answer explains in a bit more detail.

Comment: These are my using statements:`
`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;`

Also I posted the link to the video in another comment

Comment: Those seem correct, but you also have to make sure your project has assembly references to System.Net.  If you are using Visual Studio [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) will help explain what I mean

Comment: Thank you very much i'll try that and let you know

Comment: I just edited my answer a bit to give you some quick steps on checking if this indeed is your problem.

Comment: I'm getting no assemblies when I right-click on the project and adding the reference. There is nothing to add. I already have a reference to System.Net.Http

Comment: I'm not understanding when you say "I'm getting no assemblies when I right-click on the project and adding the reference. "  Does that mean there are zero assemblies checked?  Or that you do not see the "Assemblies" section?

Comment: There were none at all showing in the assemblies section - nothing to tick. I downloaded the dll and tried to add it but it says its automatically included in the build

Comment: The video says to create a Windows Form project type, did you make sure that's the project type you created?  Also, could you share a screenshot of what that Reference Manager popup looks like on your machine?

Comment: I'm not using a Windows Form i'm using UWP as I was testing this for reading JSON from a WEB API to a UWP app. Here is the references[link](http://imgur.com/b2yuGwu)

Comment: Ah, well there's your problem.  From what I can gather the code in the video is incompatible with UWP, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835974/httpwebrequest-in-uwp-c) answer.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm tearing my hair out over trying to just get a RESTFUL API to update info from the app to a MySQL database but it's literally the most frustrating thing ever

Comment: It gets easier, dont worry :).  There are caveats to different project types, it takes some time to learn the nuances between them.  Don't give up!

Comment: I know but its frustrating i've been looking at this stuff for 4 months and have got nowhere its so disheartening

Comment: What is your end goal?  Why does it have to be a UWP application?

Comment: My end goal was a UWP app that saves highscores to a MySQL database through a web API (SlashDB). Well its a big project i'm undertaking this year and I was too far into the project when I realized MySQL doesn't work with UWP anymore. UWP is what my college taught me so I have no experience in Android or Ios apps

Comment: Ah, so it has to be a mobile application?  If so, [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/) is now free and included with Visual Studio.  C# Portable Class Libraries have access to `System.Net.Http`.  As for architecture you'll prolly want to look into having a Web.API project to handle your MySQL requests and external API requests (mobile apps shouldnt speak directly to a remote database).  That way your mobile app just speaks to one server for all its needs :)

Comment: I've learnt a small bi of Xamarin but I have only a month maybe now to finish my project and this server stuff is literally the last thing I need. SlashDB is actually an online web API we're using to talk to our MySQL database

Comment: Oh well in that case you should be ok with a UWP application.  Just have to change up how you are making REST calls.  The video tutorial you are following is incompatible with UWP but there are a lot of different ways to make HTTP calls.  Try searching for "HTTP Rest calls UWP" or something similar.

Comment: I've tried so many different versions of code to try and get this working but somehow nearly all of them just don't work for one reason or another. But thank you for the help here anyway despite it being useless basically

Comment: I only have so many characters in a comment but these two articles will prolly help you get what you need accomplished.  None of the UI stuff you have done will have to change, just your logic for making Http calls.  [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt614268.aspx) article deals with the OneDrive REST API, but if you look at how its calling it you will see what you need to do for yours.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will try that and hopefully someone somewhere will smile on me :P

Comment: And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37422792/make-a-post-request-with-httpclient-in-uwpw10) one gives a little more context.